# Laravel Target is not instantiable while building

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, service-provider

I created an Artisan command **which worked** and where I injected a Kafka client service as the first parameter and a concrete class `BudgetsTransformer`, as the second parameter.

```
class ConsumeBudgetsCommand extends Command {
    public function __construct(FKafka $kafkaClient, BudgetsTransformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->kafkaClient = $kafkaClient;
        $this->transformer = $transformer;

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

AppServiceProvider class looked like:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('kafka.client', function ($app) {
            return new \Weq\FKafka\FKafka();
        });

        $this->app->bind('budget.transformer', function ($app) {
            return new BudgetsTransformer();
        });

    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind('consume:budgets', function ($app) {
            return new ConsumeBudgetsCommand($app['kafka.client'], $app['budget.transformer']);
        });

        $this->commands('consume:budgets');
    }
}
```

So far all is working properly. Then I decided to create a `TransformerInterface` which `BudgedTransformer` implements (and other future Transformers will implement it):

```
class BudgetsTransformer implements TransformerInterface
{
 // ...
}
```

and I changed the signature in the command to inject the interface instead of the concrete class:

```
class ConsumeBudgetsCommand extends Command {
    public function __construct(FKafka $kafkaClient, TransformerInterface $transformer)
    {
        $this->kafkaClient = $kafkaClient;
        $this->transformer = $transformer;

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

But I get the following issue when I try to run some `artisan` command

> In Container.php line 933:
> Target [App\Transformers\TransformerInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Commands\ConsumeBudgetsCommand].

I run previously the issue the following artisan command just in case. `cache:clear`, `clear-compiled`, `optimize` and so on but no luck.

What I'm doing wrong? Should I bind the `BudgetTransformer` in a different way I'm doing now for passing and Interface instead of a concrete class?

I added:

```
$this->app->bind(TransformerInterface::class, BudgetsTransformer::class);
```

in `AppServiceProvider::register()` and I removed

```
$this->app->bind('budget.transformer', function ($app) {
        return new BudgetsTransformer();
});
```

there, then I update in `AppServiceProvider::boot()` the command binding:

```
$this->app->bind('consume:budgets', function ($app) {
        return new ConsumeBudgetsCommand($app['kafka.client'], $app[TransformerInterface::class]);
});
```

But still not working, anyway this approach (even working) will not resolve the issue since when I want to add another different transformer implementation, let's say `CostTransformer` which implements `TransformerInterface` is gonna always inject `BudgetTransformer`. So reading the documentation in the link, I found that `Contextual Binding` could be the solution, so I substituted by:

```
$this->app
        ->when(ConsumeBudgetsCommand::class)
        ->needs(TransformerInterface::class)
        ->give(function ($app) {
            return new BudgetsTransformer();
        });
```

So in that way, I will be able to inject different implementations of transformers to different commands by injecting the interface. But still not working.

Can someone tell me how exactly declare the command binding

```
$this->app->bind('consume:budgets', function ($app) {
        return new ConsumeBudgetsCommand($app['kafka.client'], ???);
    });
```

to use that `Contextual binding`?

Comment: You don't need any of the `$this->app->bind(...`  because your app doesn't use any of them to create the `ConsumeBudgetsCommand` object. What you only need is to bind the `TransformerInterface` to the `BudgetTransformer`, so that the app would know to inject it then executing the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For binding interfaces must be use this structure https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

```
$this->app->bind(TransformerInterface::class, BudgetsTransformer::class);
```

And

```
$this->app->bind('consume:budgets', function ($app) {
    return new ConsumeBudgetsCommand($app['kafka.client'], $app->make(TransformerInterface::class));
});
```

Comment: @Averias are you try this??

Comment: yes @Davit, I tried, please read my update on the question above

Comment: The same as before: Target [App\Transformers\TransformerInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Commands\ConsumeBudgetsCommand].

Comment: Why you try to bind?? laravel must be automatically bind it. Are you use in command **protected $signature = 'consume:budgets'**??;

Comment: I want to bind the command since I'm injecting the Kafka service (as 1st param in the command). Anyway even removing the bind for the command: $this->app->bind('consume:budgets',.... and also the command declaration:  $this->commands('consume:budgets'); it doesn't work(same error), and to be honest I would like to know how to use both bindings cause it can be a use case that I will face in the near future

Comment: Still the same issue, even when I just used: $this->app->bind(TransformerInterface::class, BudgetsTransformer::class); instead of Contextual Binding, the only way that works is when I come back and pass a concrete implementation of the transformer as the second param in the command

Comment: Are you try this **$app->make(TransformerInterface::class)**? for binding **'consume:budgets'**

Comment: I tried **$this->app->bind('some-method', function ($app) {dd($app->make(SomeInterface::class))** and it is instance of SomeInterface::class implemention class. try it and show answer

Comment: I tried as u said, by adding the dd() function but still same issue: "Target [App\Transformers\TransformerInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Commands\ConsumeBudgetsCommand]." So I'm thinking that probably the issue is coming from another part, I will review the code. Thank u so much for your effort and time

Comment: Wooow finally it was an issue in the interface definition, sorry, I drove you crazy @Davit, anyway I checked your answer out and it worked properly, then I changed it by contextual binding and it worked properly. Thanks for your time and answers!